# Liferay error FileNotFoundException File name too long

Tags: tomcat, liferay

here's my problem.. 
i have recently got my liferay portal ext running on Tomcat 6.0.20. everything works fine, but
when i click some link this error comes up on the log.. some Javascript also is not working i guess.

i am also running my server on Ubuntu 9.04, used Mysql as my database.

hope you can help me

thank you in advance 
heres my error log

```
Jul 31, 2009 10:48:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke 
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/orlovs/Liferay-Portal/tomcat6020/temp/liferay/minifier/portal/html/js/everything.jsp_Q_browserId=firefox&themeId=controlpanel&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&t=1249034302000 (File name too long) 
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) 
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179) 
at com.liferay.portal.util.FileImpl.write(FileImpl.java:735) 
at com.liferay.portal.util.FileImpl.write(FileImpl.java:717) 
at com.liferay.portal.util.FileImpl.write(FileImpl.java:711) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil.write(FileUtil.java:255) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.minifier.MinifierFilter.getMinifiedBundleContent(MinifierFilter.java:224) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.minifier.MinifierFilter.processFilter(MinifierFilter.java:415) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:95) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:168) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:130) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:95) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:168) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:370) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:95) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:168) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.header.HeaderFilter.processFilter(HeaderFilter.java:132) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:95) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:168) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:86) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:95) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:168) 
at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:186) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:95) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:168) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:173) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:95) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:168) 
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocalcache.ThreadLocalCacheFilter.processFilter(ThreadLocalCacheFilter.java:46) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:95) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:168) 
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:98) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) 
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 1):

The hint is in the stacktrace:

File name too long

It considers the whole of this string to be the filename

```
/home/orlovs/Liferay-Portal/tomcat6020/temp/liferay/minifier/
portal/html/js/everything.jsp_Q_browserId=firefox&themeId=
controlpanel&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&
minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&t=1249034302000
```

Where perhaps it should be only?

```
/home/orlovs/Liferay-Portal/tomcat6020/temp/liferay/minifier/
portal/html/js/everything.jsp
```

That is, the `_Q_` sequence looks like the start of the query part of the URL, rather than part of the path

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but i think thats the way the the application is made. i've checked on my windows machine with the same application and it really created that file.

Answer (score 0):

It's either because the directory in which you are trying to create a file does not exist, or because the file name is too long.

Comment: the folder directory is there... but i think its the filename generated.. is there other way to increase the filename length that can be handled by Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Ubuntu 9.10 machine and I think it was caused by the home-directory encryption. Those "too long" filenames work fine outside my home.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug in Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/27708734).

You can work around it (for non-production use) by adding this suffix to all URLs:

```
?strip=0&js_fast_load=0
```